# Sum does not equal average

Tags: microsoft-office

Column A has ten rows of whole numbers. Column B ten rows of %. Column C is the produce of A * B. The sum of Column A * average % of Column B results in one answer, but the sum of the products in Column C results in a different answer. Why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Because the values of Col A are all different?  I think your math assumption is not correct here.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data. See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, since it is a basic high school maths question and has nothing to do with computers.

Answer (score 0):

If we simplify for 2 rows:

```
A  B   C
5  10% 0.5
8  20% 1.6

SUM(A) = 13
AVG(B) = 15%

SUM(A) * AVG(B) = 1.95
SUM(C) = 2.1
```

They're not equal in excel because they're not equal in maths

Answer (score 0):

This is a mathematical problem, and the same assumption is 2 rows, A, B, C three columns.

[image]

These 2 mathematical formulas are not the same.